# How to keep UISwitch on or off after reopening the app

Tags: ios

i have a switch
, but when the app is reopened, the last state will not be remembered. I have checked many teachings many years ago. I am using swift. How to do this?

ViewController

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modeSwitchStyleB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchBToggle(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        let state = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
        modeSwitchStyleB.setOn(state, animated: true)
}


@objc func switchBToggle(_ sender: YapDarkAndLightModeSwitch) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
        if sender.isOn == true{
            print(sender.isOn)
            
            
            AppearanceService.shared.theme = Themes.dark
            view.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = AppearanceService.shared.theme.getUserInterfaceStyle()
            
            
        }else{
            print("It's off")
            
            AppearanceService.shared.theme = Themes.light
            view.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = AppearanceService.shared.theme.getUserInterfaceStyle()
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
```

AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "switchState")
 return true
        
    }
```

Comment: Why do reset the state in app delegate ? App delegate should only set the value to a default value if the user default is not defined.

Comment: how should i modify